# Evaluating an integral along a parametrized curve.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

[image]

I was trying to do this homework problem.

I tried using the chain rule to find $z = f(x,y)$ such that we can write $x \frac{dy}{dt} - y \frac{dx}{dt} $ in terms of $\frac{dz}{dt}$.

But I could not proceed.

Comment: Have you tried expressing the integrand in terms of $t$?

Comment: A 12.3k user that ask such a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: observe that $\frac{y}{x}=\tan t\Rightarrow y=x\tan t$

Step 2: deduct $\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{dx}{dt}\cdot \tan t+\frac{x}{\cos ^2 t}$

Step 3: deduct $x\frac{dy}{dt}-y\frac{dx}{dt}=x\frac{dx}{dt}\tan t+\frac{x^2}{\cos ^2 t}-x\tan t \frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{x^2}{\cos ^2 t}=(1+2\cos t)^2$

Step 4: replace the finding at step 3 in order to evaluate the definite integral